# Prolog: P-12: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems (Modified)

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to decode a specific list with two different elements, either e.g. [4, a] or just b

I expect `decode([[4,a],b,[2,c],[2,a],d,[4,e]], X).` to result into `X=[a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e]`.

with

```
decode([], []).
decode([[N, X]|Xs], R) :-
    create_list(N, X, L1),
    append(L1, R),
    decode(Xs, R).
decode([X|Xs], [X|R]) :-
    \+ is_list(X),
    decode(Xs, R).

create_list(0, _, []).
create_list(N, X, [X|R]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    create_list(N1, X, R).
```

Generates only **false** and I have tested the create_list predicate and it works.

I have no clue what I'm missing but could just be a minor mistake. But I have tried for a while to find the problem without success so why not ask here :) The question is a modified version from the Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems (Problem 12).

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [clumped/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clumped/2) ([source](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#clumped/2)) - This only encodes, it does not decode.

Comment: Of interest: RosettaCode - Run Length Encoding - [Prolog](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Prolog) - This has predicates for both encoding and decoding. Also uses DCGs and clp(fd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the use of [`append/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) which concatenates a list of lists, but you have a list of atoms.

You may use [`append/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) to build a list with an unbound tail and pass that tail to the recursive step of your procedure, i.e.:

```
decode([], []).
decode([[N, X]|Xs], R) :-
    create_list(N, X, L1),
    append(L1, Tail, R),
    decode(Xs, Tail).
decode([X|Xs], [X|R]) :-
    \+ is_list(X),
    decode(Xs, R).

create_list(0, _, []).
create_list(N, X, [X|R]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    create_list(N1, X, R).
```

Sample run:

```
?- decode([[4,a],b,[2,c],[2,a],d,[4,e]], X).
X = [a, a, a, a, b, c, c, a, a, d, e, e, e, e] ;
false.
```

You may also get rid of append altogether by adding a third argument to create_list which holds that tail:

```
decode([], []).
decode([[N, X]|Xs], R) :-
    create_list(N, X, R, Tail),
    decode(Xs, Tail).
decode([X|Xs], [X|R]) :-
    \+ is_list(X),
    decode(Xs, R).

create_list(0, _, Tail, Tail).
create_list(N, X, [X|R], Tail) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    create_list(N1, X, R, Tail).
```

Alternatively you may get rid of `create_list` by using [length/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) and [maplist/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2):

```
decode([], []).
decode([[N, X]|Xs], R) :-
    length(L, N),
    maplist(=(X), L),
    append(L, Tail, R),
    decode(Xs, Tail).
decode([X|Xs], [X|R]) :-
    \+ is_list(X),
    decode(Xs, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of *run-length encoding* and *run-length decoding*.

Run-length encoding is easy:

```
encode( []     , []     ) .  % the run-length encoding of the empty list is the empty list
encode( [X|Xs] , [R|Ys] ) :- % For non-empty lists, 
  run(Xs,X:1,R,Rs),          % - seed the run with the first element and compute the run length
  encode(Rs, Ys)             % - then recurse down
.                            % Easy!

run( []     , Y:N , Y:N , []     ) .
run( [X|Xs] , Y:N , Y:N , [X|Xs] ) :- X \== Y .
run( [X|Xs] , Y:T , N   , Rs     ) :- X  == Y , T1 is T+1 , run(Xs,Y:T1,N,Rs) .
```

And decoding a run-length encoded list is the  opposite

```
decode( []       , [] ) .  % the run-length decoding of the empty list is the empty list
decode( [X:N|Xs] , Ys ) :- % for non-empty lists, 
  expand(X,N,Ys,Zs) ,      % - expand the run
  decode(Xs,Zs)            % - recurse down
  .

expand( _ , 0 ,    Zs  , Zs ) . 
expand( X , N , [X|Ys] , Zs ) :-
  N > 0,
  N1 is N-1,
  expand(X,N1,Ys,Zs)
  .
```

And then put it together in a transcoder that will work bi-directionally:

```
run_length_transcode( PlainText, RleText ) :- nonvar( PlainText ) , encode( PlainText , RleText   ).
run_length_transcode( PlainText, RleText ) :- nonvar( RleText   ) , decode( RleText   , PlainText ).
```